# Formula to Calculate 5 working days from created date, where created date is DateTime data type

Tags: formula-field, datetime

I found a formula online about returning a date data type for 5 working days after the case created date, but I noticed the "created date" data type is set in DateTime.

I am thrown through a loop for this, how can I extract a date data type with this DateTime value for a created date? Or rather how do I create the formula to return a DateTime value?

This is what I had for when I thought it would be a return of date data type (the formula is invalid, and I don't know how to correct it to DateTime):

```
 CASE( WEEKDAY (CreatedDate + 5), 
  1, (CreatedDate + 5) + 1 + FLOOR(3/5)*2,
  2, (CreatedDate + 5) + 1 + FLOOR(4/5)*2,
  3, (CreatedDate + 5) + 1 + FLOOR(5/5)*2,
  4, (CreatedDate + 5) + 1 + FLOOR(6/5)*2,
  5, (CreatedDate+ 5) + 1 + FLOOR(7/5)*2,
  6, (CreatedDate + 5) + 1 + CEILING(4/5)*2,
  7, (TCreatedDate + 5) - IF(1>0,1,0) + 1 + CEILING(4/5)*2,
  null
)
```

this was the error message: Incorrect parameter type for function 'WEEKDAY()'. Expected Date, received DateTime

Comment: You'll find the [DATEVALUE](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_datevalue.htm&type=5) function of use.

Comment: Thank you phil! it worked to change it to date type :) my formula was a little wonky though. to be honest, I couldn't make heads of tails of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DATEVALUE` function to convert the datetime value to the date.

Here is the updated formula:

```
CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ),
3, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 2 + 5,
4, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 2 + 5,
5, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 2 + 5,
6, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 1 + 5,
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 5
)
```

Use the `DATEVALUE( date/time )` function to return the Date value of a Date/Time. For example, to get the year from a Date/Time, use `YEAR( DATEVALUE( date/time ) ) )`.

Refer to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5) documentation for more information.

PS. I have edited the formula as above. This formula gives you the date of the 5 working days after the case createddate. for example. CreatedDate is 28/07/2023(dd/mm/yyyy) then the formula return the date is 04/08/2023(dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: Note that the original formula is unnecessarily complex using FLOOR and CEILING and offsetting everywhere. This could be simplified. Also has a typo "TCreatedDate" you carried over.

Comment: Oh, and adding days to a Datetime like this probably doesn't work...?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should do this job in a simple manner:

```
CASE(WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)),
     7, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 6
     1, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 5,
     2, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 4,
     DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 7)
```

Essentially:

1. If the CreatedDate is a Saturday (7), Sunday (1) or a Monday (2) then 5 working days later is assumed to be the following Friday - there's a question as to whether the Monday should be counted itself in the latter case, but let's assume it should - so just add the required number of days to get to that Friday.
2. If the CreatedDate is on any other day of the week, we need to move to the same day in the following week, so adding 7 days.

Putting it another way:

- On a Saturday, move to the next Friday (add 6 days).
- On a Sunday, move to the next Friday (add 5 days).
- On a Monday (if assumed inclusive), move to the next Friday (add 4 days).
- On a Tuesday, move to the next Tuesday (add 7 days).
- On a Wednesday, move to the next Wednesday (add 7 days).
- etc.

If the required period of 5 working days from a Monday is to be the following Monday, not the following Friday (you decide the rules here), simply remove the line  `2, DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 4,`.

NB: This assumes 2 weekend days that are Saturday and Sunday. This won't work places that have the weekend on different days.

Comment: wow! This is amazing, thank you! I understand now! I will rework my formula :) they have the standard weekends off

Comment: @JasmineG feel free to upvote and/or mark as best answer. Cheers.